# How can i set zoom level according to height from ground level (eg.1KM) in google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with Google API and I want to show view of any location on Google map from particular height. I don't want to assign zoom level directly. I want to calculate it dynamically with respect to height (Eg. 1Km, 2Km, 3Km, etc.). If any one have idea please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also interested in this. I mostly would like to know what would a person view from an airplane at that specific altitude.

Answer (score 0):

Try using map.setZoom(your value)

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, info) {
var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
map.setCenter(pt);
map.setZoom(your desired zoom);
}
```

Referred: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map

Comment: I don't want to assign zoom level directly,I want to dynamically calculate it with respect to height (Eg, 1 KM,2Km, 3KM etc..).

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a direct, out-of-the-box solution for your problem because it depends on the size of the device and the distance from which you look at it.

For example, if you are holding you device at 40 centimeters from your eyes, and then you move it to 50 centimeters, the perceived distance to the ground will change a lot.

Anyway, you can estimate the distance using a formula to [Calculate distance knowing actual and perceived size](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180272/calculate-distance-knowing-actual-and-perceived-size).

Using this formula you can calculate the perceived distance for each zoom level based on the perceived size of an object with a known size (a car or a building for example), the size of your device and the distance from which you're looking at it, and then find a relation to know what zoom level you need to apply to simulate a given altitude.

Take into account that this will always be an approximation because you can't be sure about the distance from which your users are looking at your map, and also because the map represents the earth in a plane, so the farther the zoom, the worse this method will be.